# Minimizing over a determinant in numpy gives "Cannot cast ufunc 'det'..." error

Tags: numpy, scipy, minimize

I'd like to minimize a determinant using numpy/scipy but I get the error "UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'det' input from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') with casting rule 'same_kind' "

Minimal working example:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

def N(xi,f):
    return np.array([[1,f],[xi,1]])

xi = 0.001
obj = lambda f: np.abs(np.linalg.det(N(xi,f)))
x0= 0.056

obj(0.054)
# returns 0.999946

m = minimize(obj, x0)
# returns UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'det' input from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

Comment: full error message please

Comment: A `lambda`, like a regular `def f` has to specify the input arguments, `xi` or what ever.  What's the relation between the `x0` search variable, and the objective function.  Sometimes it's better to use a regular `def` function definition rather than a lambda.  With that you can include `print(args)` line that shows you what `minimize` is passing to the function.

Answer (score 1):

hpaulj's suggestion was essentially correct.  This got it working:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

def N(xi,f):
    val = []
    for ff in f:
        val.append( np.array([[1,ff],[xi,1]]) )
    return val

xi = 0.001

def obj (f): 
    return np.abs(np.linalg.det(N(xi,f)))

x0= 0.056

obj([0.054])
# returns 0.999946

m = minimize(obj, x0)
```